# Python Testing whether an integer is within a certain range

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that tests whether a number falls outside of a certain range... what am I doing wrong here?..

```
def outside(testnum, beginRange, endRange):
   if testnum <= beginRange:
        return false
   if testnum >= endRange:
        return false
```

Comment: First of all `false` should be `False`.

Comment: What's the error you are receiving?

Comment: Probably want to return `True` at the very end

Comment: oh wow, yea it worked fine once I changed false to False... thanks

Comment: `return beginRange < testnum < endRange`

Comment: I have to say, the function name `outside` is terribly named. It seems to be computing if a value lies `inside` a range.

Comment: ^ I realized that right after I ran the first successful execution

Answer (score 2):

`false` should be `False` and return `True` at the end otherwise the function will return `None`(default return value) if both of the conditions are `False`.

```
def outside(testnum, beginRange, endRange):
   if testnum <= beginRange:
        return False
   if testnum >= endRange:
        return False
   return True
```

Or simply:

```
def outside(testnum, beginRange, endRange):
   return beginRange < testnum < endRange
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple one liner may work here:

```
def inside(testnum, lowthreshold, highthreshold):
    return lowthreshold <= testnum <= highthreshold

def outside(testnum, lowthreshold, highthreshold):
    return not (lowthreshold <= testnum <= highthreshold)
```

edit: realised I was indicating the INSIDE, not outside. Made it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

you need to return true at the bottom
(Also note that to me, if something was beginRange or endRange, I'd consider that inside and so I'd do < and > instead of <= and >=), and for that matter... you probably want to return true for stuff that is outside and false otherwise.  (Also note that it should be False / True instead of false / true)